# Check in JDBC that a request execute correctly

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to execute dynamic SQL in a Servlet using JDBC, I need to check either the user request was executed correctly or not.

I am ussing the Execute command wich return a boolean: TRUE indicates the result is a ResultSet and FALSE indicates it has the int value which denotes number of rows affected by the query.
And this method throws SQLException - if a database access error occurs.

So I don't see any mean to tell the user either his request was executed correcty or not (because of a bad syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a database error, you will get an SQLException.

If there is no database error, but the results are still "wrong" for your application, you have to add some extra checks in your own code (such as inspecting the number of affected rows, or running some additional queries). Maybe more constraints are also an option.

Once you have determined if there was a problem, you can inform your user about it. You will have to break it down to him in terms that he can understand (because he has no idea about how your database works), how it affects him, and what he can do about it (such as retrying it later, double-checking his input data, or contacting user support). There is nothing JDBC can do to help you with that.

If there was a problem, you probably also want to log the incident for future reference.

Comment: so there is no method to check the query syntax (MySql in my case)?

Comment: If the query syntax is incorrect, you will get an SQLException when you try to execute it. The associated error message may or may not be very helpful. There is usually no completely dynamic SQL (that the user can enter directly). It should be created by your program, and always be correct.